# MySql Query Equivalent to MsSQL Query for CREATE

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a Query for Create Statement which runs perfectly in My SQL Yog. But It comes up with errors when i run on MS SQL Server Management Studio.

My SQL Create Statement is as follows: -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countries` (
  `COUNTRY_ID` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `COUNTRY_NAME` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `REGION_ID` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`COUNTRY_ID`),
  KEY `COUNTR_REG_FK` (`REGION_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

what is the equivalent query in SQL server Management Studio.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx

Comment: Is there a tool which converts it from a My SQL to MS SQL?

Comment: I think SQL Server doesn't understand `ENGINE=MyISAM` and I'm not sure if it knows `IF NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: @Keynes [Online Converter](http://www.sqlines.com/online)

Comment: yes @AndyBrown, this tools makes my work simpler. Shall I use it for even more complex queries. Is It reliable ?

Comment: @Keynes, I can't vouch for its reliability; but for the small number of times I've converted relatively small & simple ad-hoc scripts, it's worked fine.  Treat it for what it is, a free online tool with unknown veracity.  I'm sure you can find more Enterprise solutions if you're prepared to pay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE countries 
    (
      COUNTRY_ID varchar(2) PRIMARY KEY,
      COUNTRY_NAME varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
      REGION_ID decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TABLE countries (
    country_id CHAR (2) PRIMARY KEY,
    country_name VARCHAR (40) DEFAULT NULL,
    region_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (region_id) REFERENCES regions (region_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```